# How can I create rounded background on hover?

Tags: css

I try to have below rounded border on hover:

[image]

```
.memberInfo .TagList .Interests:hover {
    background-color: #dfe7f5;
    color: #206CC3;
    border-radius: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

I have something weird with above code.

How can I make such a border?

Comment: set a border too with the radius `border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 10px;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zut7sjLe/

Comment: Can be your selector ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a single-value syntax. For instance: [`border-radius: 5px`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius), so that radius of `5px` would be applied to all corners.

The four-value syntax stands for `top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left`.

Therefore, considering `border-radius: 10px 0px 10px 0px;` the top-right and bottom-left corners won't get rounded.